# How to detect a defective LED in an Image

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In my project i have a set of led's in a board with same pattern.While seeing that led's using a camera,found white holes in an image.(first attachment)

(1). My first requirement  is i need to find No of working and not working led's.This one is much easier when i used blob detection using opencv. i found successfully.

(2). My second requirement is i need to draw working led's in green color and not working led's in red color.i was struggled here.

if all the led's are working properly i got the center of all the blobs easily and using that center points i was drawn in green color.But the problem is if any one led's are not working.i did not get any white hole in an image.I did not get any blobs in the image.How can i draw a not working led in red color.

please find the attachment below which is useful to understand my problem.Thanks in advance

[image]
 Input Image
[image]

if all the led's are working i drawn like this

[image]
One led Was not working.Now i need to identify that not working led and i will draw it in a red color like my fourth attachment. 
[image]

Comment: How do you know led is working or not, by turning it's ON?. Then you may proceed with brightness of each led.

Comment: Yes...While Switch on my circuit the led's are glow.At the time i captured LED Lights and process.Based on the each brightness only i have to decide LED is ON or OFF conditions.But if any one LED is not working i did not get any white light in the image.How can i detect that in my image.Since i want to know in Image processing side is there any possibility to identify that Not working LED.

Comment: Then you can proceed as Francesco's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the LED arrangement and scale is constant (which probably should be, if this is a manufactured part), can't you just register to the test image a "reference" one with all the LEDs working, and then find blob-sized-and-shaped mismatches, which would be indicative of a malfunctioning device?

Comment: aranga: to follow Francesco's advice, you can also consider taking a known good image of LEDs, find the centers, and then use those center points to perform a least squares fit on the center points for each inspection image. Then about each center point you can check for a white blob (LED) of the appropriate size.

Comment: Francesco's :Thank you.I tried template matching its not working properly because of the led brightness are varied.since my Scale is constant i did not try any image registration techniques can you suggest some image registration techniques or examples.

Comment: First think I'd try is to actually downscale, binarize both template and image to get rid of luma variance, then blur a bit to help matching with a soft edge transition, then just use any search algo to register. Even exahustive search should converge quickly if you can start from a good guess for the translation. Hard to say what would be most performant without looking at a large enough sample of your images.

Answer (score 0):

As Francesco wrote in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860929/15485), if these assumptions are valid:

1. the sizes of the LEDs, as seen in the image, are constant and known;
2. the arrangements of the LEDs is constant and known;
3. a working LED gives bright grey levels, a not working LED gives dark grey levels;

then, as suggested by Rethunk, you can try a simple algorithm like this one:

1. Start from your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC0lr.jpg where all
   the LED are working.
2. Get from that image the centroids of all the green blobs, call them `c_i`
3. Get from that image the radius of all the green blobs, call them `r_i`
4. When you have to inspect a new image: for each `c_i` compute the histogram of the pixels contained in a circle centered at `c_i` and with radius equal to `a_i*r_i` (where `0 < a_i <= 1`). If a percentage `p_i` of the number of pixels considered in the histogram have the grey level greater than a threshold `t_i` then draw a green disk centered at `c_i` with radius `a_i*r_i`, else, draw a red disk.

Find with some experiments the right values for `a_i`, `p_i`, `t_i`.